# locale_get_default() function issue on localhost

Tags: php, localization, wampserver, intl

Im using wampserver on localhost with;

- PHP 5.3.13
- Apache 2.2.22
- Enabled php_intl.dll extension

But i got following error while using `locale_get_default()` function

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function locale_get_default() in

Or using `Locale::getDefault()` function

> Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved with Following Link**

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,80704,116793

> Ok, I got it to work. It looks like Apache can't find the icu*.dll
>   files (in the php directory).
>
> So, one solution is to add "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9" (or similar
>   directory) to your system PATH.
>
> The other solution is to copy the icu*.dll files to your apache's bin
>   directory.
>
> A third option is to copy the icu*.dll files to your Windows system
>   directory (system32 or SysWOW64).

Comment: The best solution is to copy the icu files into the Apache folder. Of course when you switch PHP or Apache version you need to make sure you do it again. If you copy them to system32 or add a folder to the path it is less flexible, and you may end up with the wrong files being pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

*snip* didnt read:

Are you sure the extension is loaded? (See `phpinfo();`)

Comment: I couldnt see in phpinfo but i was enabled from settings and checked in php.ini file. Because of what?

Comment: If it does not show as loaded in phpinfo(); it is not loaded hence the undefined function error. Are you sure the .dll is the proper version for the used PHP version?

Comment: I solved with following link: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,80704,116793 thanks