# Fatal error: Call to undefined function locale_get_default()

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function `locale_get_default()` on linux hosting (cpanel). The PHP Version is 5.3

I use this to detect users location and language

Here PHP documentation and it has a sample code

http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdefault.php

I had same issue in localhost using xampp and got it resolved using this post 
[locale_get_default() function issue on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520026/locale-get-default-function-issue-on-localhost)

But in web hosting i get the same error

Comment: What version of linux? cpanel? etc

Comment: So... find this function. It's not a standard PHP one, so we can't help you - we have no idea what you're doing with this function.

Comment: @user689 SO is kind of the google of technical answers so...yeah...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function requires PECL intl >= 1.0.0...
check this;

http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/en/function.locale-get-default.php

Check if it installed. If not, ask your hosting provider to install it.

Comment: hosting provided says they won't be able to install php_intl() extension since its a shared hosting. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue, just by enabling intl extension from the cPanel. Thanks a lot for the valuable information.